# Open flight simulation data (trajectory, aerodynamics, wind tunnel simulations.. etc)?

Tags: data-request

Are there any open datasets with flight simulation results?

I am looking for anything related to flight trajectory simulation, aerodynamics simulations, wind tunnel simulation. Anything that is used before actual flights (during prototyping).

I found a single set of data from NASA DASHlink:
https://c3.nasa.gov/dashlink/resources/140/
However, I would prefer to have a larger dataset, and possible from collection which is widely known and used before by other people (researchers).